# How can I sort multiple outputs of a Google Cloud Function together?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-pubsub

I have a cloud function that is triggered 4 times to process a different set of data in each execution. Every time the function runs, it produces a list.

I would like to somehow get these lists together and sort them after the 4th execution is over.

Is this possible to achieve?

Comment: How are you differentiating each of the 4 calls?  Different input to the same function?  How are the 4 function calls related?

Comment: Yes, it's 4 different inputs to the same function. They are published one after another and trigger the function 4 times. The data is then processed in each of the function calls and I would like to somehow get that data together and sorted if that's possible. @GariSingh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As specified in **[documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/bestpractices/tips#use_global_variables_to_reuse_objects_in_future_invocations)**:

> There is no guarantee that the state of a Cloud Function will be preserved for future invocations. However, Cloud Functions often recycles the execution environment of a previous invocation. If you declare a variable in global scope, its value can be reused in subsequent invocations without having to be recomputed.

Meaning that, it's possible to preserve a list of items between two or more function executions, but you have **no guarantees** that this list will keep its state, because cold starts can always happen for scalability reasons. When a cold start happens, everything is recreated.

If there’s a need to share state across function executions, then a secondary service dedicated to persist shared data should be accessed during each execution, such as **[Firebase](https://firebase.google.com/firebase-and-gcp)**.